# How can i prevent to have same values for one user

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this kind of tables:

https://ibb.co/sPn5zT7

Here in the `UserPl` table, the `ProgrammingLanguageId` and `KnowledgeId` are foreign keys, connected with Primary Keys of `Knowledge` and `ProgrammingLanguage` table.

I want to make when I insert for example

```
insert into userPLs values(1,'a7ac3486-e852-42c0-a458-9075eb5ed7d7','Doe',1,1)
```

here Doe says that he knows C# with basic knowledge. I want to prevent in the next insert to be impossible for Doe, to be inserted again something like this:

```
insert into userPLs values(1,'a7ac3486-e852-42c0-a458-9075eb5ed7d7','Doe',1,2)
```

or

```
insert into userPLs values(2,'a7ac3486-e852-42c0-a458-9075eb5ed7d7','Doe',1,2)
```

because he once said that his knowledge of C# is basic.

I AM USING MS SQL SERVER

How can I achieve this?

Comment: How about creating a unique index on (UserID, ProgrammingLanguageId)?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name looks like sql-server, but he should confirm.

Comment: Try searching for `INSERT OR UPDATE` for your specific RDBMS. Also, I  strongly suggest you reformat your queries to explicitly state the columns for your `INSERT` rather than rely on column order. This will payoff greatly in future maintainability.

Comment: it it MS SQL GUYS

Comment: I can make unique index on UserId because may ;later for the same user,there will be insert for another language with another knowledge

Comment: Would a unique constraint work?

Comment: Has nothing to do with your question but the column 'Name' in the table 'UserPl' seems redundant and may cause errors.

Comment: @shawnt00 How can i make the  unique constraint on KnowledgeId when next time another user will have for another language the same knowladge?

Comment: @Code It's a multi-column constraint.

Comment: wHAT IS multi-column constraint.? PLEASE EXPLAIN

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent the insert with a constraint.

```
alter table UserPl   
add constraint UserLanguageSkillLevel
unique (UserId, ProgrammingLanguageId);
```

You'll still gave to catch failed inserts or modify the front end to eliminate the opportunity to add contradictory information in the first place.

A uniqueness constraint is ultimately enforced with an index. If you create a unique index directly rather than by using a constraint you could also apply the `ignore_dup_key` index setting and let the engine silently discard bad inserts. I'm not going to endorse that as an ideal approach but it might be useful as a temporary stopgap.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set a unique index, where required

Answer (score 0):

Having `Primary key` / `Cluster Index` on the table `UserPl` would enforce whatever the combination of your needs i.e.

- If **User** cannot know multiple **programming languages**, then key goes

```
Create clustered index CLU_UserPL on UserPl (UserID)
```

- If **User** can can know multiple **programming languages**, but cannot have multiple level of **knowledge** in programming languages, then key goes

```
Create clustered index CLU_UserPL on UserPl (UserID, ProgrammingLanguageID)
```

- If **User** can can know multiple **programming languages**, also have multiple level of **knowledge** in programming languages, then key goes

```
Create clustered index CLU_UserPL on UserPl (RecID) --- might be new identity column

or 

Create clustered index CLU_UserPL on UserPl (UserPLID)
```

Comment: @Sheker with the second line of code it does not work sir (Create clustered index CLU_UserPL on UserPl (UserID, ProgrammingLanguageID))

Comment: I needed to delete the primary key index,now i can insert multiply employees with same id,and knowledge id problem is not fixed.I've tried

Comment: @Code, yes, you must remove existing PKey/Clustered Index as a table cannot have more than one. However, didn't get "knowledge ID problem is not fixed". it's simple, after applying key (as mentioned second scenario), you cannot insert combination of `UserID`and `LanguageID` twice

Comment: I deleted the existing PK's and after that i still can insert multiply time same values for user id ame language id

Comment: @Code, yes, you cannot insert, i believe, that's what you wanted? if not try other combinations as mentioned in answer depending on your requirement. I hope, the description made it clear!

Comment: Two minutes ago i described false,i can still insert multiply times same values for KnowledgeId with your solution - John 1,1 once,second time i can still insert John 1,3 with your solution.That's what i wanted to say.

Answer (score 0):

this can be achieved by using constraints UNIQUE. 
Here is a detailed articles about UNIQUE constraint [W3School UNIQUE Article](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp<br)

Simple words, UNIQUE is a constraint that will ensure there is no same value allowed in the selected field.

If you want to have another way to prevent Doe to insert new values in the table, you would like to use another method which is **IF EXISTS**

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM userPLs WHERE UserId = 'THE USER ID')
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Data Already Exists! Insert will be ignored!'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Data doesn''t exists! Proceeding to insert the data!'
    //Start inserting the data
END
```

**UPDATED ANSWER**

Here is the modified SQL Query with IF EXISTS but with another condition.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM userPLs WHERE UserId = 'THE USER ID' AND ProgrammingLanguageId = 'The ID')
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Data Already Exists! Insert will be ignored!'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Data doesn''t exists! Proceeding to insert the data!'
    //Start inserting the data
END
```

The query above will solve your issue. If you are wondering how does it works, below is a simple explanation:

1. The query will check for the UserId first. Does the UserId has been registered to Database?
2. Next, the query will also check, does the data that will be inserted to Database (ProgrammingLanguageId) also exists in the Database for the selected user?
3. If the UserId is already registered and the UserId has the same ProgrammingLanguageId with the ID that will be inserted to database, it will ignore the insert and shows "Data Already Exists! Insert will be ignored"
4. But IF **The UserId is already registered in the Database but HAS NO ProgrammingLanguageId that match with the data that will be inserted, it will start insert the data**

For a better usage, I think you should create a trigger that will occur whenever an Insert is being executed.

Comment: Yes but later the same employee can have another language with another knowledge

Comment: Hi, @Code. I have already update the answer so it will be more fit for you case. Please check it out.